# The remainder when $33333\ldots$ ($33$ times) is divided by $19$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$A= 33333\ldots$ ($33$ times). What is the remainder when $A$ is divided by $19$?

I don't know the divisibility rule of $19.$

What I did was
 $32\times(33333\times100000)/19$ and my remainder is not zero and this is completely divisible by $19.$

This is a gmat exam question.

Comment: see here Test for divisibility by 19. Add two times the last digit to the remaining leading truncated number. If the result is divisible by 19, then so was the first number. Apply this rule over and over again as necessary. 
EG: 101156-->10115+2*6=10127-->1012+2*7=1026-->102+2*6=114 and 114=6*19, so 101156 is divisible by 19.

Comment: Do we have $33$ threes ?

Comment: no we have 33333(33 times) @Peter

Answer (score 1):

We have $$A=3\cdot \frac{10^{165}-1}{9}$$

We have $10^{165}\equiv 10^3\equiv 12\mod 19$ , so we have $10^{165}-1\equiv 11 \mod 19$

Modulo $19$ we have $9^{-1}=17$, hence $A\equiv 3\cdot 17\cdot 11\equiv 10\mod 19$

Comment: Remark : You can reduce the exponent modulo $\phi(19)=18$, so $10^{165}\equiv 10^3\mod 19$

Comment: Why 10^165? @Peter

Comment: What formula have you applied? @Peter

Comment: A number consisting of $n$ ones, also called rep-unit, denoted with $R_n$, can be expressed by $R_n=\frac{10^n-1}{9}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $19$ is prime, the first $18$ powers of $10$ (starting with $10^0$) will produce all of the remainders $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 18$ (although not in that order) when each power is divided by $19.$ Hence the sum of these $18$ powers of $10,$ namely $111111111111111111,$ satisfies
\begin{align}
111111111111111111 &\equiv 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + 18 \\
&\equiv (1 + 18) + (2 + 17) + \cdots + (9 + 10) \\
&\equiv 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 \\
&\equiv 0  \pmod{19}.
\end{align}

So $111111111111111111$ is divisible by $19,$ and also any multiple of 
$111111111111111111$ 
(such as $333333333333333333 \times 10^n$ for any non-negative integer $n$)
is also divisible by $19.$
It follows that if a number's decimal representation consists of $165$ digits each of which is $3,$ the first $9 \times 18 = 162$ digits are a number divisible by $19.$ So we just have to deal with the last three digits,
that is, what is the remainder when $333$ is divided by $19$?

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 19\!:\,\ \dfrac{\color{#c00}{10^{\large 33}}\!-1}3\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}8\!-\!1}3\equiv\dfrac{-12}3\equiv -4,\ $ by $\,\ \overbrace{\color{#c00}{10^{\large 33}}\equiv\dfrac{1}{10^{\large 3}}}^{\Large \overbrace{10^{18N}\ \equiv\ 1}^{\rm Fermat}\ }\equiv \dfrac{2^{\large 3}}{20^{\large 3}}\equiv \color{#c00}{\dfrac{8}1}$

Comment: Or $\ 165\equiv -15\equiv 3\pmod{\!18}\,\Rightarrow\dfrac{10^{\large 165}\!-1}3\equiv \dfrac{10^{\large 3}\!-1}3\equiv 333\equiv -47\equiv 10\pmod{\!19}\  $ $\quad$

Answer (score 0):

Here's something crude but it takes less than the whole $33$ steps:
$$
\begin{array}{rccccccccccccccccc}
& & & 1 & 7 & 5 & 4 &  \\[12pt]
& 19) & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & \ldots  \\
& & 1 & 9 \\[12pt]
\text{remainder} = 14 \rightarrow & & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
& & 1 & 3 & 3 \\[12pt]
\text{remainder} = 10 \rightarrow & & & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
& & & & 9 & 5 \\[12pt]
\text{remainder} = 8 \rightarrow & & & & & 8 & 3 \\
& & & & & 7 & 6 \\[12pt]
\text{remainder} = 7 \rightarrow & & & & & & 7 & 3
\end{array}
$$
If we ever get $0$ as a remainder -- say after $n$ steps -- then we can discard the first $n$ digits, and the the next set of $n$ digits if that many remain, then the next set of $n$ digits after that if that many still remain, and so on. In that way we reduce the problem to one with fewer than $n$ iterations of the digit $3$.

Comment: I think we get remainder $0$ after $17$ steps, so the sequence of remainders then repeats and the final remainder will be the one that appeared after $16$ steps.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition $A=(10^{33}-1)/3$
*(if that is what you meant - a $33$-digit number, all threes)*

$\bmod 19$, we have
$10^2\equiv 5$,
$10^3\equiv 12$,
$10^4\equiv 6$,
$10^5\equiv 3$,
$10^6 \equiv 11$,
$10^9\equiv 12\cdot 11 \equiv 18\equiv -1$,
$10^{18}\equiv (10^9)^2\equiv 1$,
$10^{33}\equiv 10^{15}\equiv -1\cdot 11 \equiv 8$.

Then since $10^{5}\equiv 3$,
$3^{-1}\equiv 10^{18-5}\equiv 10^{13}\equiv 10^910^4 \equiv -6\equiv 13$ and
  $(10^{33}-1)/3 \equiv (8-1)\cdot 13 \equiv 91 \equiv 15 \bmod 19$

---

If you actually meant a $165$-digit number, all threes, then the above preparatory work can support that easily:

$10^{165} \equiv 10^{18\cdot 9}10^{3} \equiv 10^{3} \equiv 12\bmod 19$ and
 $(10^{165}-1)/3 \equiv (12-1)\cdot 13 \equiv -8\cdot -6 \equiv 48 \equiv 10 \bmod 19$

Comment: Actually lil Fermat ends up being easier, e.g. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly squaring mod $19$ and noting that $3\cdot13\equiv1\pmod{19}$:
$$
\begin{align}
10^2&\equiv5&\pmod{19}\\
10^4&\equiv6&\pmod{19}\\
10^8&\equiv17&\pmod{19}\\
10^{16}&\equiv4&\pmod{19}\\
10^{32}&\equiv16&\pmod{19}\\
10^{33}&\equiv8&\pmod{19}\\
10^{33}-1&\equiv7&\pmod{19}\\
\frac{10^{33}-1}3&\equiv7\cdot13&\pmod{19}\\
&\equiv15&\pmod{19}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Edit After a Clarification to the Question**

Above, it is shown that $10^{33}\equiv8\mod{19}$. Squaring twice and multiplying by $10^{33}\equiv8\mod{19}$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
10^{66}&\equiv7&\pmod{19}\\
10^{132}&\equiv11&\pmod{19}\\
10^{165}&\equiv12&\pmod{19}\\
10^{165}-1&\equiv11&\pmod{19}\\
\frac{10^{165}-1}3&\equiv11\cdot13&\pmod{19}\\
&\equiv10&\pmod{19}\\
\end{align}
$$

---

**Computing $\boldsymbol{\frac13\pmod{n}}$**

If $n\ne0\pmod3$, then either $n$ or $2n$ is $\equiv-1\pmod3$. This means that either $\frac{n+1}3$ or $\frac{2n+1}3$ is an integer. That integer is $\frac13\pmod{n}$ (that is, multiplying it by $3$ gives $1\bmod{n}$).

Comment: It would probably help to say how you computed $\,1/3\equiv 13\pmod{19},\,$ e.g. $\,1/3\equiv -18/3 \equiv -6.\  $ Note that the OP clarified in comments that the expt is $165$ not $33\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: that comment was indeed posted before I finished my answer, but not before I last read the question. Unfortunately, I did not go back and reread the comments after I was finished with my answer to see that the OP meant 33 repetitions of 33333. As for $3\cdot13=39=2\cdot19+1$, I arrived at that simply by looking at the first three multiples of $19$, $0,19,38$ to find one that was $-1\pmod3$.

Comment: To be clear, no critique was intended, it was just a remark in passing that I thought worth appending since I was already commenting about the inverse. Of course such timing issues happen to any frequent answerer.

Answer (score 0):

We know $333\dots 18$ times will be divisible by $19$.

So we check for the remaining $333\dots 15times$.

We can write it as $3 * 111,111,111,111,111$

Further we can write it as $3 * 111 * 1,001,001,001,001$

Further writing it as $3 * 111 * (1,001,001,001,000 + 1)$

$$3 * 111 * (1001 * 1000 * 1,000,001  +  1)$$

Now dividing it by $19$ we get remainders as

$$3 * -3 * ( -6 * -7 * -7  +  1)$$

$$-9 * (-6 * -8  +  1)$$

$$-9 * 49$$

$$-9 * -8$$

$$72$$

$$72/19$$

Remainder is $15$.